# Find out what's causing random restarts if /var/log/syslog is empty

Tags: linux, logs, rsyslog, reboot

I'm dealing with a server that randomly reboots every once in a while. Checked the power and nothing is wrong there. However the syslog is alway completely empty when it comes to the reboots, see the following:

```
Sep 21 04:15:01 pve CRON[27553]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 21 04:17:02 pve CRON[30038]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 21 04:20:37 pve rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.4.2" x-pid="2506" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Sep 21 04:20:37 pve kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

The first 2 lines are normal, the second two means the system has rebooted, without any notice in the log it seems...

Is there any other way or logs to help find out what's causing this?

Comment: `dmesg` maybe? or, if your system uses systemd (please provide some info in that direction), try `journalctl -xe`

Comment: watchdog most probably. It is only happy when seeing some lines there by default. Check if you have it installed *and* if you are starting it.

Comment: @schaiba persistent systemd logging wasn't on so enabled that and now waiting for it to happen again

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Can you elaborate or provide some sources? I have a `/dev/watchdog` device, however watchdog package isn't installed. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: If the watchdog package is not installed, then my theory is not valid.